# Sufficient condition for function’s existence

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable and $f(a,b) = 0$. A condition that ensures the existence of a unique continuously differentiable function $\phi$ such that $b = \phi(a)$ and $f(x,\phi(x)) = 0$ for all $x$ sufficiently close to $a$ is

1. $D_1f(a,b)>1$
2. $D_1f(a,b)<1$
3. $D_2f(a,b)>1$
4. $D_2f(a,b)<1$

The only thing I understand(not sure about this also) about this question is that it is talking about a condition that would ensure the existence of a function which would define the level curve of $f$, I don’t really have a clue about how to go about this question. Also it would be great if someone could provide a formal proof rather than simply explain why the correct option is correct. I would really appreciate some help.

P.S. $D_i f$ is the partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t $i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the implicit function theorem, the condition for this to hold is that $D_2f(a,b)$ is invertible, so in this case as it is a scaler, that it is non-zero. Thus the answer is #3.

For details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem.